# Handle different responses of restful service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jaxb, cxf

I'm integrating to an existing system so the API is fixed.
The service is pretty straight forward and looks like this.

```
@Path("/get_orders/")
public interface OrderService {

@GET
@Path("/")
Orders getOrders(@QueryParam("from_date") String fromDate);

}
```

Everything works fine as long as the query will result in at least one order.
In that case the xml will look something like

```
<orders>
  <order>
    <id>11</id>
    ...
    ...
    ...
  </order>
</orders>
```

The problem is if the query will result in zero orders, the xml will look like this

```
<error>
  <message>Orders not found</message>
</error>
```

How can handle a different XmlRootElement?

I'm guessing that I would need some kind of wrapper class that can hold both a Orders object and an Error object but I have no idea how to configure jaxb in order for it to work.

I did find something about handling data binding without XmlRootElement annotation but haven't figured out if that is what I need.

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-HandlingJAXBbeanswithoutXmlRootElementannotations

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you change the method signature? When you return `Orders`, jax-rs is building a response object with the return value as an entity in the response. Instead of returning `Orders`, you could have the method return the `Response` object and build it up yourself. For example, `return orders.isEmpty() ? Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(new Error("Orders not found")).build() : Response.ok(orders).build();`

Comment: What you are suggesting with building different responses is on the server side. I'm on the client side of the web service.
I can change the method signature (of the interface that is consuming the web service) which I have tried so it returns a Response object instead. 
The problem is that I haven't figured out a way to inspect if the entity before reading it.

    `Response response = orderServce.getOrders(fromDate);`
    `Orders orders = response.readEntity(Orders.class);`  // This will throw an exception if the response is an error.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Is the http status code the same in both cases? If not, you could simply decide which type to read based on the status code. Normally I would expect a wrapper object with a choice, or some kind of additional information to indicate the type of the entity (e.g. a status code or header) from the service.

Comment: Unfortunately the response codes are identical (that is, 200). It's only the xml that is different.

Comment: Check this out: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html.  You should be able to create a type that represents both responses.  Your JAX-RS code wont look as nice, but it should be do-able.

Comment: This appears to be a error message (even the best approach in this case is return a empty `<orders/>`). This error message is sent with a different Http status code, like 500?